# how to find difference between two vectors as a function of time-lag in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, signal-processing, time-series, vectorization

First time posting a question here! Will happily take any advice`||`criticism I can get.

We have two vectors: `v1` and `v2`. Assume `length(v1)` >> `length(v2)`. I move a window of size `length(v2)` along the vector `v1`. At each lag index, from the windowed portion of `v1` I subtract `v2`. I then sum the terms of the resulting vector and return this sum for every lag index along the length of vector `v1`. For simplicity, let's ignore the edge cases.

I've done this with a `for` loop, but the length of my vectors is on the order of 10^9 [and larger], and even though the calculation is simple, it appears to take a long time to just iterate through the whole thing.

Any ideas? I suspect there is a function that does something like this, but I have had no luck finding it.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what exactly you're doing. Can you provide a short example? If you're just summing all the elements, then it doesn't matter how you align your vectors; you're just leaving off different numbers of elements at each end.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I can see exactly why my explanation was not a good one. I have edited the question to better reflect my actual meaning (I hope it makes more sense now).

Comment: You're really summing the difference between vectors, and not some norm of the difference?

Comment: That's actually the exact thing I was going to attempt next. Figured it would be good to think about a simpler operation first, but it looks like the same trick probably won't work... Am I stuck using a `for` loop in that case?

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-in functions that would work in that case. You might look into mex-functions, which are c extensions to matlab. They are fairly easy to write for simple operations like this, and will have much better performance than a for-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'll allow me to reframe the question, you basically want a windowed sum of one vector. You're then subtracting from this the sum of some other vector.

My solution would be to use the cumulative sum function in matlab (`cumsum`) as follows:

```
l1 = length(v1);
l2 = length(v2);
windowSum = cumsum( [v1 zeros(1,l2)] ) - cumsum( [zeros(1,l2) v1] );
returnVal = windowSum - sum(v2);
```

This assumes that `v1` and `v2` are row-vectors. It pads `v1` with zeros on the right, takes the cumulative sum, then subtracts the cumulative sum with the zeros padded to the left. This results in a vector such that `windowSum(i)` is the sum of the `length(v2)` elements of `v1` preceeding index `i`. Depending on how you want the edges handled, what you want the length of the vector to be, etc., this should solve your problem.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, the first step is exchanging the order of operations: summation with subtraction.  This works because summation is linear.

Comment: This is definitely the clever way to do it. Isaac, you are a gentleman and a scholar.